# Return C++ iterator reference

Tags: c++, vector, reference, iterator

### Example in which it does work as expected

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct MyClass{


  const std::vector<float>::iterator& begin(){
    return myvec.begin();
  }

  const std::vector<float>::iterator& end(){
    return myvec.end();
  }
  std::vector<float> myvec;
};

int main(){

  std::vector<float> mainvec(8,0);

  MyClass myClass;

  myClass.myvec = mainvec;

  for (std::vector<float>::iterator it = myClass.begin();
      it != myClass.end();++it){
    std::cout << *it << " " ;
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

In this code I get the following output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

### An example which does NOT works as expected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct MyClass{


  const std::vector<float>::iterator& begin(){
    return myvec.begin();
  }

  const std::vector<float>::iterator& end(){
    return myvec.end();
  }
  std::vector<float> myvec;
};

int main(){

  std::vector<float> mainvec(8,0);

  MyClass myClass;

  myClass.myvec = mainvec;

  const std::vector<float>::iterator& end_reference = myClass.end();

  for (std::vector<float>::iterator it = myClass.begin();
      it != end_reference;++it){
    std::cout << *it << " " ;
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

In this code I get the following output:

```
"empty output"
```

### The first code example

It has the problem in which I invoke (erroneously) the vector `begin()` and `end()` instead of MyClass methods.

I have the following minimal code to represent my doubt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct MyClass{


  const std::vector<float>::iterator& begin(){
    return myvec.begin();
  }

  const std::vector<float>::iterator& end(){
    return myvec.end();
  }
  std::vector<float> myvec;
};

int main(){

  std::vector<float> mainvec(8,0);

  MyClass myClass;

  myClass.myvec = mainvec;

  for (std::vector<float>::iterator it = myClass.myvec.begin();
      it != myClass.myvec.end();++it){
    std::cout << *it << " " ;
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

I get the following warnings on lines 8 and 12:

```
returning reference to local temporary object [-Wreturn-stack-address] [cpp/gcc]
```

but when I compile and run the program, I get:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

So, it seems that the local reference is not destroyed when it returns the `myvec.begin()`. When I first wrote the code, I didn't thought it was going to be a problem, as in my head the begin() method from the vector would return a iterator reference to the first vector place, this iterator for me is not being allocated when I do myvec.begin(), but is a reference to this iterator. So, this warning shouldn't appear, as I am not allocating memory. But since I don't know how this mechanism works, I would like to learn it for writing consistent code. It seems that I can ignore this warning, can't I?

Comment: Where'd you get the idea that `begin()` returns a reference?

Comment: Where in [the description of `std::vector::begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) do you see any mention of a reference result? It returns an *object*.

Comment: @remyabel just as I thought things would be… instead creating an iterator object, it would sound more reasonable that it would be a const reference…

Comment: Calm down guys hahaha. @WhozCraig I wrote the code without looking the documentation and saw the warnings. Indeed it does not. But I would like to know why it does not crash the code…

Comment: @Werner: You'd like to know why undefined behaviour doesn't give well-defined behaviour? Because it's undefined. (In this case, it probably just means that the storage for the destroyed object hasn't been reused before it's copied into a local variable, so it still contains the old value. You can't rely on that behaviour though.)

Comment: @MikeSeymour I see, so I need the program not to allocate anything in the memory region which is freed to write and thus the example is not safe, am I right?

Comment: @Werner: Indeed, it's always UB to use an object after it's lifetime has ended, and always wrong to return a reference to an automatic variable or temporary. There's no (portable) way to stop the program reusing its memory once its lifetime has ended. You need to return the iterator by value.

Comment: Fyi, your *actual* invoked-code is valid because you *never invoke your* `begin()` *and* `end()` *members of* `MyClass`. Rather, you invoke `myClass.myvec.begin()` and `myClass.myvec.end()` directly. Your Ub-thriving members are uncalled.

Comment: @WhozCraig you are right! I've just changed the code and it result on an empty answer (no zeros are printed). Sorry for making you to check such a dumb mistake…

Comment: @MikeSeymour, with the correction by WhozCraig, I have added an example in which the code does not works as expected. Now I will be happy to return by value hahaha. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

std::vector::begin returns indeed a temporary object
(see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/begin/)

<s>Your code is valid since you are binding the temporary object to a const reference (would not be legal with a non const reference), and copy it right away in a local variable `it`.</s>
**edit:** My mistake. This is indeed also UB to return a const reference from a temporary.

However assigning this reference to another const reference with a longer lifetime would result in undefined behavior as the lifetime of a  temporary object is only extended to the lifetime of the const reference it is directly assigned to.

I would recommend taking into account the warning and return an iterator.

I also recommend reading http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/

Comment: I will read the recommendation! It seems to be exactly the complementation I am needing. However, I still have the feeling that the const reference (even with a limited span time of the temporary object) is exactly what is needed in the example…

Comment: I don't believe this to be correct. The const reference must be at-least within the same scope as the instigated temporary (and is such in all of the linked article examples where Herb denotes it as valid). That is not the case here. The temporary is most-definitely *gone* once the called function returns. §12.2/5 [class.temporary] of the standard describes this, though not in the easiest terms, to be sure. If this isn't an accurate assessment then everything I ever learned about temporary lifetime extension via const-reference just went out the door.

Comment: With the addition of the third paragraph on, this appears to be correct., therefore +1.